# Gerrit Trigger on multiple SCM in jenkins not working

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit

I am trying to setup Jenkins for a project. I use git as the SCM and gerrit as code review tool. My project consist of many repository, so I am using MultipleSCM plugin in Jenkins to check-out different repos. I have configured Gerrit Trigger for initiating a build when code checkin happens. The Problem is that when a user makes a change in any one repo the all, all the other repos gets the same CHANGE details which are not valid in any other repo.

```
    > git rev-parse 873a6b7209411fa825f35da1c6fbc7f280cff06b^{commit} # timeout=10
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE
```

How to solve the problem? Please help. Is there any work around.
Thanks in advance.

---

Jenkins Version: 1.588
Plugins Used: git, gerrit-trigger, multiple-scm.
I have two gerrit projects (gerrit1 and gerrit2). I am using both the gerrit project in same jenkins job(because they are dependent). If one developer makes a change in gerrit1 and push to gerrit, Jenkins get a trigger and start building. This work fine when there is one gerrit project. But in my case, if there is a change in gerrit1, gerrit2 will have the same change parmeters in jenkins. Hence the checkout fails for the gerrit2 since the branches may be different.

Comment: Soem more details about your configuration would be useful

Comment: Did you specify the gerrit server in the gerrit trigger configuration?

Comment: @uncletall yes gerrit server is configured.. The trigger is working....The Problem is while checkout of unmodified repo..

Comment: I guess it is the multiple SCM plugin. You are having multiple repos in one config? Doubt if that is going to work with Gerrit

Comment: @uncletall Is there any workaround for this....

Answer (score 0):

Those do not support each other. You'll want to create a separate job and trigger for each repository.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and was able to configure Gerrit trigger with `Multiple SCMs` plugin.
Here is my solution (actually, this was one of the recommendations from Gerrit plugin page):

1. For git repository which you would like to configure click on `Advanced` button and put to `Refspec` field this: *refs/changes/*:refs/changes/**
2. Also for the same repository configure `Branch Specifier` like this: *$GERRIT_REFSPEC*

After that triggered builds in Jenkins were updated to correct branch/ref.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good solution would be to create git submodules. The Parent one Will contain all actual repositories